# Pointers assignment in C

Tags: c, pointers

```
int y = 1;
int k = 2; 
int *p1; 
int *p2; 
p1 = &y;
p2 = &k;
p1 = p2;
*p1 = 3;
*p2 = 4;
printf("%d", y);
```

I am getting the output as 1, can somebody explain me why? I was expecting it to be 4.

Comment: **Why** were you expecting that? We can't debug your brain if you don't include the source code...

Comment: Put `*p1=2` *above* the `p1=p2` line and see what it does - reason why the output is now 2, but still not 4 (or 3).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below comments explain how this works:

```
int y=1;
int k=2; 
int *p1; 
int *p2; 
p1=&y; //pointer p1 holds the address of y
p2=&k; //pointer p2 holds the address of k
p1=p2; //pointer p1 now holds the address which p2 holds, which is the address of k
*p1=3; //the value which p1 points to is now 3 (so k equals 3 as well)
*p2=4; //the value which p2 points to is now 4 (so k equals 4 as well)
printf("%d",y); //y is still 1
```

However if you did `printf("%d",k);` the value 4 would be printed

Answer (score 2):

To keep this simple let's say `&y=3` and `&k=4`.

```
int y=1;
int k=2; 
int *p1; 
int *p2; 
p1=&y;  // p1=3
p2=&k;  // p2=4
p1=p2;  // p1=4
*p1=3;  // p1=4 so k becomes 3
*p2=4;  // p2=4 so k becomes 4
printf("%d",y); // we get 1 because y was never changed
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do:

```
p1=p2;
```

you are basically copying the address of variable k from p2 into p1. So after that step both pointers are pointing to variable k, so if you dereference either p1 or p2 you will actually be changing the value of variable k and not y.

When you do:

```
*p1 = 3;
```

You are assiging 3 to variable k. Then when you do:

```
*p2 = 4;
```

You are assigning 4 to the variable k again. That's why y remains unaltered and when you print it gives you 1.

Answer (score 1):

The statement `p1=p2;` sets `p1` to point to variable `k`.  So both of the following assignments:

```
*p1=3;  
*p2=4;
```

only affect variable `k`, so `y` remains 1.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, although I'd love to hear how you arrived at 4.  p1 gets assigned the address (i.e. pointer to) y, but 2 lines later that gets replaced by the address for k.  Thus, neither p1 nor p2 point to y, so y doesn't change.